# request.POST.get('category_id') gives single value

Tags: python, django

I have a post request and the request gives the following value:

```
request.POST
<QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'AbyDcwOtSyPwuC1JxeVUKJFk33XhH2us'], u'category_id': [u'15', u'26', u'7', u'8']}>
```

I want all the values in category_id in a list. But if I try to access values with **request.POST.get('category_id')** it gives me only the last value [u'8'] not the hole list.

Is my approach wrong? If I am then what is the correct way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `request.POST.getlist('category_id')`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to **change `.get()` to `.getlist()` to get all the values.**

```
request.POST.getlist('category_id')
```

**`.get()` QueryDict operation:**

`.get()` operation on Django's [`QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) object returns the last value of the `key` if it has multiple values.

> [`QueryDict.__getitem__(key)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.__getitem__)
>    Returns the value for the given key. If
>   the key has more than one value, `__getitem__()` **returns the last value**.

**`.getlist()` QueryDict operation:**

If you need to get all the values for a particular key, you need to use [`.getlist()`.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist)

> [`QueryDict.getlist(key, default=None)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist)
>    Returns the data with the
>   requested key, as a Python list. Returns an empty list if the key
>   doesn’t exist and no default value was provided. It’s guaranteed to
>   return a list of some sort unless the default value provided is not a
>   list.